# Binary Tree Level Order Traversal in leetcode

Tags: c++, tree, c++14, binary-tree, tree-traversal

got error when tried to run the code "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc"
Code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class Solution {
public:

    vector<vector<int>> levelOrder(TreeNode* root) {
        int d = height(root);
        vector<int> lol[d];
        vector<vector<int>> ans;
        queue<TreeNode*> q;
        if(root!=NULL)
            q.push(root);
        for(int i=0; i<=d;i++){
            ans.push_back(level(i,q,lol[i]));
        }
        return ans;
    }

    vector<int> level(int i,queue<TreeNode*> q,vector<int> lol){
        if (q.size() != 0)
        {
            for(int a=0;a<=i;a++){
                lol.push_back(q.front()->val);
                q.push(q.front()->left);
                q.push(q.front()->right);
                q.pop();
            }
        }
        return lol;
    }

    int height(TreeNode* root){
        if (root==NULL)
            return 0;
        else{
            int lef = height(root->left) + 1;
            int rig = height(root->right) + 1;
            if(lef>rig)
                return lef;
            else
                return rig;
        }
    }
};
```

Output should be in the form:
[[3],[9,20],[15,7]]

Could anyone tell where is the mistake in my code.
I am new to programming in C++ and at leetcode so it is diffult to find mistakes.
Please help.

Comment: Debugger.  Use a debugger.  A debugger will allow you to step through your code, *watch*ing values in variables.  Often, using a debugger is faster than correctly posting to StackOverflow and *waiting* for somebody to inspect or debug your program for you.

Comment: Where exactly is it throwing that exception?

Comment: You may not want to pass matrices by copy (either returning them or passing as a copy in the parameters).  I recommend passing them by reference as parameters (prefer constant reference if the matrix is not modified).

Comment: https://leetcode.com/playground/ULtBc9JE
This is the debugger.

Comment: Nope, that's not a debugger. That's a fancy webpage that allows you to input code which it then compiles an executes for you. To run a debugger, you'll need to install a compiler + debugger, and then debug locally. GCC with GDB is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you push nodes into queue without checking if they are NULL or not. When popping from queue you also dereference them without checking.

Comment: I tried this but it is still giving the same error.